# Adding a value to a column in an array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am a physics undergrad whose only computer programming experience is a python class I took over the summer, so I am very green when it comes to all things python. I am writing a python script that will taken in a set of coordinates from a .xyz file and then shift the coordinate system to be centered on one of the coordinates in the file. That is, one coordinate will be made to be zero, and all the other coordinates will be translated in the x, y, and z directions to match.

My script can read in the file and translate it to an array, but when I try to change the values in the temporary array I get this error:

```
File "E:/Computational Python Scripts/Test.py", line 29, in Carbon_Two_Origin
    Temp_Array[i][1] = XYZ_File[i][1] + 0.32101

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Here is the entirety of the script that is causing me the problems:

```
import numpy as np
def file_name():
    while True:
        file_name_input = input('Type in the name of the xyz file: ')
        try:
            file = open(file_name_input)
            lines = file.readlines()
            file.close()
            Geometry = []
            for line in lines:
                Geometry.append(line.split())
            print('You have selected', file_name_input)
            return Geometry
        except IOError:
            print('That is not a valide file name. Try again.')

#Defines the variable XYZ_File to be the input file given by user
XYZ_File = tuple(file_name())

#REMOVE THIS LATER
print(XYZ_File)

#Generates a new set of position vectors that has the target carbon, C2, at origin.
def Carbon_Two_Origin():
    Temp_Array = np.array(XYZ_File)
    for i in range(len(XYZ_File)):
        for j in range(len(XYZ_File[i])):
            Temp_Array[i][1] = XYZ_File[i][1] + 0.32101
            return Temp_Array

New_Geometry = Carbon_Two_Origin()

print(New_Geometry)
```

Comment: Is `XYZ_File[i][1]` a string? If not, it needs to be converted.

Comment: you should load the file directly with `numpy.loadtxt` and then you used vectorized addtion (e.g., to shift the first column, do `array[:, 0] += 0.32101`, if `array` is the variable into which you loaded your file )

Comment: (if you edit the question to include the first ten lines of the file, I'll show you wnat I mean)

Comment: the main problem here is that `line.split()` returns as list of strings, not numbers

Comment: `Temp_Array[i][1] = float(XYZ_File[i][1]) + 0.32101` will fix the problem. You have made a list of strings in the command `line.split()` and python doesn't support applying operations between different types (which is allowed in some languages); so, you have to cast the string variable to `float` in order to be able to add it to another `float` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paul H said the problem is split return str so you have two option: convert everything to float on the split or before the sum operation. I prefer on split.

```
import numpy as np
def file_name():
    while True:
        file_name_input = input('Type in the name of the xyz file: ')
        try:
            file = open(file_name_input)
            lines = file.readlines()
            file.close()
            Geometry = []
            for line in lines:
                Geometry.append([float(number) for number in line.split()])
            print('You have selected', file_name_input)
            return Geometry
        except IOError:
            print('That is not a valide file name. Try again.')

#Defines the variable XYZ_File to be the input file given by user
XYZ_File = tuple(file_name())

#REMOVE THIS LATER
print(XYZ_File)

#Generates a new set of position vectors that has the target carbon, C2, at origin.
def Carbon_Two_Origin():
    Temp_Array = np.array(XYZ_File)
    for i in range(len(XYZ_File)):
        for j in range(len(XYZ_File[i])):
            Temp_Array[i][1] = XYZ_File[i][1] + 0.32101
            return Temp_Array

New_Geometry = Carbon_Two_Origin()

print(New_Geometry)
```